# JavaEE6 enable / disable webfilter without recompile

Tags: jakarta-ee, annotations, java-ee-6, servlet-filters

I'm migrate application to the new JavaEE6 standard. And annotation is very easy to use when creating new filters. I only need to add a @WebFilter annotation to my POJO classes and it works well.

What confused me is: all filters with the annotation would be automatically loaded by the container. This is not desired sometimes. I may create a set of filters and different webapp would choose to use only subset of these filters. So the question I have: is there an easy way to enable / disable filters based on different deployment, while still allow me to use the simple WebFilter annotation for each filter class?

I found this article when searching on this top:
[Dynamically registering WebFilter with Java EE 6](http://blog.eisele.net/2011/06/dynamically-registering-webfilter-with.html)

But this article seems to suggest not using annotations on each filter class, and load them via a ServletContextListener directly referencing each filter class. It doesn't seem to be an optimal solution.

Thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not possible.

Your best bet is to extend the filters with a check on some `web.xml` context param, or a VM argument, or an environment variable which indicates that the filter should not be used.

E.g.

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    if ("true".equals(System.getProperty("com.example.DISABLE_FILTER"))) {
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
        return;
    }

    // Original filter code here.
}
```

which can be disabled by supplying VM argument `-Dcom.example.DISABLE_FILTER=true`.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Since the post, I've used a similar approach as your reply but have individual flags for each filter from a config file, through injection similar to approach discussed in this blog:
http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/how_to_configure_java_ee

Comment: I accidentally downvoted your answer ....and there's no way to upvote it  because my vote  is locked...until the question is update :(.  I'm sorry.

Comment: @obe6: You can undo the vote when the post is edited. I've just edited it.